# Using Android Fingerprint API to log in user

Tags: android, authentication, android-fingerprint-api

I have an app where the user enters their username and password to log in, this is then passed to our server, verified and then we receive a validation response, straight forward and simple.

I am now looking at implementing the fingerprint API to log the user in.  I've gone through the tutorials, written the sample code etc and I understand that it generates a public key which can be sent to the server.  My question though is if there is no data to encrypt (user name and password) as the idea here is to simplify and speed up the process of login what is the process?  I'm not looking for code, just an explanation of the process of someone has already implemented this for login.

Any help or guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Hello, Did you manage to make this possible?

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing, would like to know the solution